# Can I have multiple toasts in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am coding an application for Google Sheets and when searching for duplicates in a sheet I want to inform the user. But the duplicates appears quite one after the other and it seems to me that there is only one toast displayed at a time. I was not able to find any way so the older ones would stay.

Is there a way to solve the using toasts? Or could you recommend any other solutions?

Comment: How are you executing the function?

Comment: @Cooper, I am exploring the possiblity of using sidebar...also learning GAS in general. So GAS does not support multiple toasts?